# Ошибка при создании чекбоса

Tags: java, android, xml

При создании чекбокса в Android Studio выдает ошибку

> "exception raised during rendering:Binary XML file line #-1:error inflating class"

Версии API понижал, не помогает, либо выдает ошибку рендеринга, либо вообще не отображает чекбокс на предпросмотре.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это проблема в самой студии попробуйте обновится или используйте другую тему оформления или измените api в самой студии (в layout preview) . А вообще [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544129/exception-raised-during-renderingbinary-xml-file-line-1error-inflating-class) посмотрите, такая же проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка появляется начиная с 17 - 19 api, проблема решается, если все делать от главного потока.

Comment: имею ввиду создание LayoutInflater объекта  и его использование